# Pixcels or percentage for phoneGap apps design using bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, phonegap-build

I'm trying to build a PhoneGap application using bootstrap, but I thinking about the best approach to start building the app, should I use pixcels for heights, or percentage according to the height of mobile screen after I got it using jQuery `$(window).height();` ? for example the header and footer 10% for each, and body (content) 80%.
I've the PSD with the largest mobile size  (1080px) width and height (3823px) depending the content of the page ...

And what is featured, using Mobile jQuery or standard jQuery with bootstrap ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To Allow content to be responsive for tablets as well as small screen smart phone, Bootstrap is a good option to choose, In order to enhance fluid like responsiveness to your application try using percentage as its a good practice with responsiveness concerned.

You could even use vw & vh for better results refer: http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units

Comment: thank you for your answer, I think vw & vh is the best for phonegap apps because it's controlling the font sizes too.

Comment: My pleasure.. you may appreciate by accepting the answer

Comment: I've question, how to determine the unit of vw & vh from my PSD ? according to what ? after searching I found equation 1px = (100 / document.documentElement.clientWidth)vw .. but it's not clear enough for me ! @sumeet

Comment: The principles behind vw, vh are simple: 

They represent percentages of the Device viewport’s width and height, respectively.

1vw = 1/100 of the current viewport width, i.e. 1% of the total width of current device viewport

15vh = 15/100 of the viewport’s current height or 15% of the total width of current device viewport

Both vw and vh can take any positive number: integers and floating point values are all valid.

Simillaryly, 

1vmin = 1vw or 1vh, whichever is smaller
1vmax = 1vw or 1vh, whichever is larger